# オブジェクトは、このプロパティまたはメソッドをサポートしていません (エラー 438)

Tags: vba, excel

BAPI BAPI_USER_GETLISTからテーブルの値を読み込んで、ユーザが存在しているかどうか判断したいです。

```
Public Function CheckUser(iCurrentRow As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim oBAPIUserCheck As Object   'BAPIオブジェクト格納用変数
    Dim iCntReturn As Integer   'Returnオブジェクト確認用ループ変数
    Dim oSelection As Object    'Returnオブジェクト確認用ループ変数

    'ユーザ登録BAPIオブジェクト生成
    Set oBAPIUserCheck = oRFC.Add("BAPI_USER_GETLIST")

    'Import ParameterをBAPIオブジェクトにセット
     oBAPIUserCheck.Exports("WITH_USERNAME") = "X"

    Set oSelection = oBAPIUserCheck.Tables("SELECTION_EXP")
    oSelection.Item("PARAMETER").Value("PARAMETER") = "USERNAME"
```

ここで、掲題のエラーが発生しました。なぜでしょうか。

Comment: もう回答はついていますが、何処でエラーが発生しているか把握はしていますか？ブレークポイント貼ってステップイン実行するなりすれば発生箇所の特定が出来て、「あ、これ未定義だ」とかなるかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問に書かれたコードで、oRFCは定義されていません。

それなのに、「oRFC.Add("BAPI_USER_GETLIST")」と定義されていないoRFCのAdd（oRFC.Addとなっているので、AddはoRFCのプロパティかメソッドだと推測される）を使おうとした為、
『このプロパティまたはメソッドをサポートしていません』というエラーになったのです。

プログラムの最初のほうで、oRFCにAddというメソッドもしくはプロパティを持つクラスのオブジェクトを代入しておけば、このようなエラーは起きません。